# Is there a container format or active FUSE filesystem that handles transparent compression?

Tags: compression, zfs, fuse

I tried ZFS on OSX a while back and I liked the results (lz4 really helped boost performance on a typically low-performing microSD card I tested on) but I wasn't a fan of the memory usage, my system was hitting swap far too quickly. I've been trying to find a FUSE-based solution but a lot of projects that seem perfect for my needs - like fusecompress or lessfs - are dead or don't have OSX ports.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try limiting the size of the ZFS ARC?